# How to fix button shape?

Tags: python, tkinter

Buttons shapes are different for Windows and Linux. I need square buttons. How can I fix it?

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

buttons = [[None] * 3 for _ in range(3)]
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        but = buttons[i][j]
        but = tk.Button(frame)
        but.grid(row=i, column=j)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: You will need to set a 1x1 pixel image in each button and then resize it base on pixels from there.

Answer (score 2):

The buttons by default take width and height in terms of size of characters. Because of this it is hard to get an exact square. What we can do however is add a 1x1 image to the button and this will tell the button to take width and height in pixels instead.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
tk.Frame(root)
my_image = tk.PhotoImage(file="./Colors/1x1.gif")

for x in range(3):
    for y in range(3):
        tk.Button(text="", image=my_image, height=40, width=40, relief="groove").grid(row=x, column=y)

root.mainloop()
```

Update:

Here is a version with the 1x1 pixel in a string format that PhotoImage can read.
Now with `ompound="center"` so you can use text with the 1x1 image in the same button.

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
tk.Frame(root)
my_image = tk.PhotoImage("iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=")

for x in range(3):
    for y in range(3):
        tk.Button(text="X", image=my_image, height=40, width=40, relief="groove", compound="center").grid(row=x, column=y)

root.mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to write `tk.PhotoImage(file="./Colors/1x1.gif")` as code without image on disk?

Comment: @Ufx yes.  I just do not recall where I can find an embedded image. But it is possible and I am sure I have seen a post somewhere where a person does that.

Comment: @Ufx Found a cool site that can create base64 encoded strings for something like this [png-pixel.com](http://png-pixel.com/)! Tested it with PhotoImage and it worked.

Comment: It seems like texts on the buttons are not drawing now.

Comment: @Ufx fixed now. You need to use `compound` with the button to use both text and image.

Comment: With any size after placing symbol to the text width and height become bigger for about two pixels.